# JspRuntimeLibrary: "this trick avoids escaping issues"

Tags: java, unicode

I came across the following code yesterday in the [source code of Jasper's `JspRuntimeLibrary`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bluestemsoftware.open.maven.tparty/jsp-2.1/6.1.5/org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspRuntimeLibrary.java#158):

```
public static char coerceToChar(String s) {
  if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
    return (char) 0;
  } else {
    // this trick avoids escaping issues
    return (char)(int) s.charAt(0);
  }
}
```

I am intrigued by this comment - what are the escaping issues that this "trick" avoids?

Comment: Don't trust a library that has code like `Double.valueOf(s).doubleValue()`.

Comment: Maybe you will find something interesting in this commit's comments : http://osdir.com/ml/dev-tomcat.apache.org/2012-11/msg00123.html

Comment: @Berger yep, that's basically what I thought - that it is redundant. Seems like the change wasn't widely integrated, though (e.g. [not here](https://java.net/projects/jsp/sources/svn/content/trunk/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspRuntimeLibrary.java)). Would you like to write up a brief answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this link to comments on the commit removing this "trick" : [Re: svn commit: r1406384](http://osdir.com/ml/dev-tomcat.apache.org/2012-11/msg00123.html)

> The (char)(int) trick would make sense if the original data were a
>   byte or an int. **It makes no sense if the original data is a char**.
>
> For a byte the trick is needed to get rid of the sign (for an
>   ISO-8859-1 character in the range 128-255).

It looks like the trick wasn't relevant for a character, hence it was removed .

Comment: I did suspect that the comment had a [Fermat-like](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.co.uk/2005/05/problem.html) quality. Thanks for the info.